# Dynamically generate font awesome with icon name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

Let's say I have `var icon_name = 'facebook'`, how can I generate the corresponding font awesome dynamically?

is there a method available that can be used?

e.g `fontAwesome.get("icon_name")`

Comment: Just create a function that adds to a given element the class name of the icon you want.

Comment: @AngelPolitis any example ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate an icon element by the icon name:

```
getIcon = (iconName) => document.createElement('i').setAttribute('class', 'fab fa-' + iconName)

document.body.appendChild(getIcon('facebook')) //adds it to the body
```